# Лента участника не локализована должным образом

Tags: дефект, статус-завершено, локализация, нет-в-transifex, rss

В профиле любого участника на вкладке "Активность" в самом низу страницы есть такая ссылка как ["лента участника"](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/feeds/user/176217):

> [image: лента]

Содержимое полученной страницы не локализовано должным образом. В частности:

- Заголовок (как в тексте страницы, так и блок title) (отсутсвует перевод `User`):

  > [image: user]
- Ответ (отсутсвует перевод `Answer by`, `for`):

  > [image: answer]
- Комментарий (отсутствует перевод `Comment by on`):

  > [image: comment]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для ранее отсутствующих строк добавлены переводы:

> [User $DisplayName$](https://www.transifex.com/stack-exchange/stack-overflow-ru/translate/#ru/english/105167511?key=cd2cadabbbc1e7968115376525f1be7b)
>   Участник $DisplayName$

> [Answer by $OwnerDisplayName$ for $QuestionTitle$](https://www.transifex.com/stack-exchange/stack-overflow-ru/translate/#ru/english/105167509?key=0fe66adae56540ca871dd91d111aebd5)
>   Ответ участника $OwnerDisplayName$ на вопрос «$QuestionTitle$»

> [Comment by $DisplayName$ on $PostTitle$](https://www.transifex.com/stack-exchange/stack-overflow-ru/translate/#ru/english/105167510?key=c84b8e137538a0096ecb9afd80fb768c)
>   Комментарий участника $DisplayName$ на сообщение «$PostTitle$»